# Dropdown menu update view

Tags: ios, swift

I have a table view as a dropdown menu inside of a view controller. The table view is just another view inside of the actual view which opacity is being changed on click.

The user is able to pick different items to display by using the dropdown. Now if the user pick an item, how can I update the view? Since obviously I want to immediately show the user the new item's data.

Is there another approach I should choose?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let item = carsArray[indexPath.row]
        currentCar = item.name
        buttonDropdown(self)
        defaults.set(currentCar, forKey: "currentCar")

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: please share code of didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Also, which view do you want to update?

Comment: see edit, it works - but only as i leave and come back to the vc.

Comment: you are only updating data in UserDefaults. you need to update your view as well. share your screenshot of your UI for better understanding

Comment: @ParthBhuva I did `currentCar = item.name`

Comment: What is your UI components? What you will update on actual view (color, path, frame) or you want to change data?

Comment: @CoderACJHP I want to change displayed data - eg. button text, label text, which is usually done in viewdidload()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an method that update your UI componenet data and call it when you changing your data inside `didSelectItem` func...

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let item = carsArray[indexPath.row]
    currentCar = item.name
    buttonDropdown(self)
    defaults.set(currentCar, forKey: "currentCar")
     // update your UI
    updateUIComponents(currentCar: currentCar)

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}

private func updateUIComponents(currentCar: Car) {
    confirmButton.setTitle(currentCar.name, for: .normal)
    headerLabel.text = currentCar.detail
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Plus I have a container View which contains further data inside of a TableViewController - I tried reloadData() but it didn't work

Comment: This is different question, if this answer helped you accept it to help others also

Answer (score 0):

If the tableview related implementation is in the same view controller then on selection of any item didSelectIndexPath delegate method will be called. On call of this method you can change the view or details in main view of the view controller.

If the tableview related implementation is in another view controller then you can use your customised protocols to pass the selected items' data to the main view controller from the controller which has the tableview related implementation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The tableview is implemented inside of the same vc. I use `didSelectRowAt` to change the view - but the actual view won't be updated until I leave the view controller again and come back. How can i reload it?

Comment: May I know what exactly are the UI changes you want to do on selection of any option in drop down?

Comment: I want to change displayed data - eg. button text, label text, which is usually done in viewdidload()

Comment: You can create a separate function which sets the button text and label text(according to the option selected in dropdown) and whenever the option is selected from the dropdown you can call that function to change the UI in the view controller.